# Ember testing: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the run-loop's autorun

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, ember-cli, ember-qunit, ember-testing

I am trying to write a simple Ember integration test and continue to get the frustrating run loop error despite using `Ember.run`. I've had a nightmare of a time trying to get this to work, if anyone could help me I'd be so grateful. Specifically, I can see the test sign in and begin loading the next page (as it should), but as soon as the test finishes I get that error. This is regarding the second test, the first passes (as nothing is async I believe).

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import startApp from 'jobs-tuftsdaily/tests/helpers/start-app';
import exists from 'jobs-tuftsdaily/tests/helpers/start-app';

var App;

module('Integration - Landing Page', {
    setup: function() {
        App = startApp();
    },
    teardown: function() {
       Ember.run(App, 'destroy');
    }
});

test('Should load content', function() {
  visit('/').then(function() {
    ok(exists("*"), "Found HTML!");
    ok(exists('label:eq(4)'), "Slug label on page");
  });
});

test('Should sign in test user', function() {
  Ember.run(function() {
    visit('/').andThen(function() {
      return fillIn("input[name=email]", "test@test.com");
    }).andThen(function() {
      return fillIn("input[type=password]", "password");
    }).andThen(function() {
      return click("button");
    }).andThen(function() {
      ok(1, "stupid test passed");
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What does the production code (under test) look like for this app? My guess is some async code is throwing this but it's hard to tell w/ out more detail

Comment: I'm getting this same issue, but only in firefox, not chrome. have not tested phantom or safari or ie

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem..

Answer (score 5):

I realize I am late to the party, but here goes anyway:

Somewhere in your component or application code (that is, NOT in the test code), you probably listen to some event outside of Ember (e.g. a DOM event, through jQuery, or something like that), but try to interact with it during that handler's run. These handler functions must be wrapped in `Ember.run.bind()`, or they won't have a runloop during a test. `Ember.run.bind()` will also set `this` for you during the handler.

If you don't wrap your event callbacks in `Ember.run.bind()`, the code will probably still run without hassle during a normal run of the application because the autorun feature will find runloop-demanding (for example, if you schedule something using `Ember.run.schedule()` during the handler) interactions with Ember in the code and start a runloop for them, but it's turned off in tests.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue in a component's integration test. The error is:

> Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the
>   run-loop's autorun.
>
> You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in a run.

And I found the reason of problem for integration tests. I'm rendering the component with the following code:

```
let myobject = Ember.Object.create({x:1});
this.set('param', myobject)
this.render(hbs`{{my-object param=param}}`);
```

After rendering, updating `myobject` as below is causing the error.:

```
myobject.set('x',2);
```

Because it is not inside of an ember run-loop.

Instead of this erronous calling, updating the value should be done as one of the followings:

```
this.set('param.x',2); 
//OR:
this.set('param', Ember.Object.create({x:1}); 
//OR:
Ember.run(()=>{
    Ember.set(myobject,'x',2);
});
```

For your case: I didn't try but my opinion is that async test helpers such as *visit, click, fillIn* can be used in acceptance tests not in integration tests because of the following reason.

Comment: `myobject.set('x', 2);` vs. `this.set('param.x', 2);` helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping your tests in `Ember.run` won't help as the error you are getting is not happening because the test code but the code of your application. In your sign in route you must be doing some asynchronous requests (like AJAX or `setTimeout` even) and in their handlers you perform some Ember API executions (like setting, transitioning, anything).

If you would like any exact help about that you need to post your code in the route/controller.

I recently published an ebook about the Run Loop, including the autorun mechanism that can be [downloaded here](http://on.netguru.co/ember-ebook-form).